# How to get a log file from end user device in Android?

Tags: android, google-analytics

I need to get logs which is stored as a log file in end user device, for getting that I can implement send feedback option and make user send the file to a email address given in intent.

But I need something better than this like google analytics or some other logging stuff which is easy to use where we can upload a file, and still manage other log events too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase, it's have many feature to use.

**Report Crashes on Android**

`Firebase Crash Reporting creates detailed reports of the errors in your app. Errors are grouped into issues based on having similar stack traces, and triaged by the severity of impact on your users. In addition to receiving automatic reports, you can log custom events to help capture the steps leading up to a crash.`

You can watch docs in here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android

Comment: But I want a log file saved on device, not crash details.